# Stubing a static private method inside a Utils class with powermockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm having the following flow:

```
manager.getObject.doSomthing();
```

Where doSomething() calls a static function from a Utils class, that in turn, calls a private static function e.g:

```
public class obj {
  public void doSomething(){
    Utils.do();
  }
}

public class Utils {
  public static void do(){
    int test = doPrivate();
    ...
    ~do unrelated computation~
    ...
  }

  private static int doPrivate(){
    return someComplexMethod();
  }
}
```

And I would like to mock the doPrivate, so I would still be able to test the `do()` method
Any way to achieve it with powermockito?

Answer (score 0):

Using powermock-api-mockito you can achieve this.
You can mock specific static method of a class. Below is the syntax:

```
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher.method;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier.stub;
stub(method(Utils.class, "doPrivate")).toReturn(response);
```